# Multi search filter using hooks with ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, react-hooks

I have a search filter for each column of my Table, using Hooks in ReactJs, but I get an error like-

> Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

When I type in the `TextField`.

Would anyone know where this error came from?

**Here is my code:**

```
function FournisseursTable(props) {

  const classes = useStyles();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const fournisseurs = useSelector(
    ({ fournisseursApp }) => fournisseursApp.fournisseurs.data
  );
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);
  const [data, setData] = useState(fournisseurs);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(10);
  const [order, setOrder] = useState({
    direction: "asc",
    id: null
  });

const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");

  const handleChangeSearch = e => {
    setSearchTerm(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(Actions.getFournisseurs());
  }, [dispatch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(
      searchTerm.length === 0
        ? fournisseurs
        : fournisseurs.filter(fournisseur => {
          const filtersKeys = Object.keys(searchTerm);
          const hasCorrespondences = filtersKeys.map( key => 
           fournisseur[key].toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm[key].toLowerCase())).every(curVal=> !!curVal);
            return hasCorrespondences;
          })
    );
  }, [fournisseurs, searchTerm]);
```

**And the `TableCell` with the `TextField`:**

```
<TableCell className={classes.headerTableCell} >
 <Tooltip className="w-full" title="Sort" enterDelay={100}>
  <TableSortLabel
   className="w-full"
   direction={order.direction}
  >
   Code fournisseur
  </TableSortLabel>
 </Tooltip>
 <TextField
  margin="dense"
  InputProps={{ className: classes.inputSearch }}
  className={classes.rootSearch}
  label="Rechercher"
  name="Recherche"
  variant="outlined"
  fullWidth
  onChange={handleChangeSearch}
 />
</TableCell>
```

Thanks

**EDIT (for the code to work):**

Modification of `handleChangeSearch`:

```
const handleChangeSearch = type => (e) => {

    const newSearchTerm = {
      ...searchTerm,
      [type]:e.target.value
    }
    if(e.target.value === ""){
      delete newSearchTerm[type]
    }
    setSearchTerm(newSearchTerm);
  };
```

And modification of `useEffect` :

```
useEffect(() => {
    const filtersKeys = Object.keys(searchTerm);
    setData(
      filtersKeys.length === 0
        ? fournisseurs
        : fournisseurs.filter(fournisseur => {
            const hasCorrespondences = filtersKeys
            .map( key => fournisseur[key].toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm[key].toLowerCase()))
            .every(curVal=> !!curVal);
            return hasCorrespondences;
          })
    );
  }, [fournisseurs, searchTerm]);
```

And finally, call `onChange={handleChangeSearch("codeFournisseur")}` in the `TextField`

Comment: `fournisseur` does not contain `key`, because `Object.keys(searchTerm)` will be `["0", "1", ...]` when searchTerm is a string..

Comment: This is a very strange piece of code. If searchTerm is a `string`, why do you `map` it's keys like it's an object?

Comment: Ok thanks, I had an error in my handleChangeSearch function. With some help,  by changing this and changing the setData function a little bit, it works fine. (I made an edit in the code above)